# Skype messages from more than 3 months ago

Tags: skype

If skype deletes messages from as far back as February from an account is there anyway to recover these or are they gone for ever? The reason for this question is that a friend is involved in a court case and the messages that cannot be accessed any more would help her cause.

Comment: When I log in from a new computer, suddenly a lot of "deleted messages" keep appearing for me. Try installing a virtual machine, and install Skype there. (May worth a try.. but you can also contact Skype support I guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the maximum is 30 days unless required or permitted by law. Contact Skype to confirm for your area.

section 12, third paragraph
http://www.skype.com/intl/en/legal/privacy/general/#12